# Find values from one range in another range

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to run the following code the debugger stops at the line `temprow = rgSkalaD.Find(element.Value).Row` giving me the error

> Run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set?

I just have no idea why. Holding my mouse over `temprow` it shows me the right value. Could anyone help me here.

```
sub test()
Set rgSkalaV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B700")
Set rgSkalaD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A700")

Dim element As Range
For Each element In rgSkalaV
    Dim temprow As Long
    temprow = rgSkalaD.Find(element.Value).Row
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(temprow, rSIf) = THisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(element.Row, 5)
Next element

End Sub
```

What the code does:
I want to find each element from Range 1 in Range 2. If I find the value I want to copy something a few columns beside this value from the first Range + 5 columns.

Comment: If `element.Value` is not found, `Find` will return Nothing and `Nothing.Row` will give error 91.  Try `Set rgTemp = rgSkalaD.Find(element.Value)` `If Not rgTemp Is Nothing Then` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code like this:

```
Sub test()
    Set rgSkalaV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B1:B7")
    Set rgSkalaD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A7")

    Dim TempRng As Range
    Dim element As Range

    For Each element In rgSkalaV
        Set TempRng = rgSkalaD.Find(element.Value)
        If Not TempRng Is Nothing Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(element.Row, rSIf) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(element.Row, 5)
        End If
    Next element
End Sub
```